How to connect to SQL database using AD user instead of SQL user from a wildfly application?
I can connect our Wildfly 10 application to my local Windows SQL server using SQL Authentication. How do I do it using my Windows user and AD?
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS" pool-name="testDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test;</connection-url>
    <driver>sqlDriver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>test</user-name>
        <password>test123</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>

